# Keyboard shortcut to allow opening unsigned pkg file?

Tags: keyboard, finder, pkg

I prefer to use keyboard shortcuts rather than the mouse. Is there a a way to define a keyboard shortcut equivalent to Right-Clicking a pkg file and choosing "Open", which warns about opening an unsigned package?

Note this is not the same as the regular File->Open, which simply rejects opening the package altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) using a macro such as this:

[image: When hotkey pressed, for each file in the Finder's selection, execute shell script]